# Scala: using Nothing for singleton instances of polymorphic types

Tags: scala, polymorphism, singleton

Given a polymorphic trait like

```
 trait Transform[T] { def apply( t: T ) : T }
```

one might like to implement various specialized instances, such as

```
 case class Add[Double] extends Transform[Double] { def apply( t: Double ) ... }
 case class Append[String] extends Transform[String] { def apply( t: String ) ... }
```

etc. Now a frequently desired transform is also the identity transform. Instead of specializing identity for each type T, it appears preferable to use just one singleton instance for all types T. My question is: what is the best way to accomplish this in Scala?

Here is what I found so far: looking at how List[T] implements List.empty[T] and Nil, I tried using Nothing as the type T. This seems to make sense, since Nothing is a subtype of every other type:

```
 object Identity extends Transform[Nothing] {
    def apply( t: Nothing ) = t
 }
```

This seems to work. However, wherever I then want use this instance as-is, like here:

```
 val array = Array[Transform[String]]( Transform.Identity )
```

I get the compiler error "type mismatch; found: Identity.type, required: Transform[String]". In order to use it, I have to explicitly cast it:

```
 ... Identity.asInstanceOf[Transform[String]]
```

I am not sure this is the best or even the 'proper' way to do it. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Kim Stebel points out your `Transform[T]` is invariant in `T` (and has to be because `T` occurs in both co- and contra- variant positions in `def apply(t : T) : T)` so `Transform[Nothing]` is not a subtype of `Transform[String]` and can't be made to be.

If your main concern is the instance creation on each call of Kim's `def Id[A]` then your best model is the definition of `conforms` in in Predef,

```
private[this] final val singleton_<:< = new <:<[Any,Any] { def apply(x: Any): Any = x }
implicit def conforms[A]: A <:< A = singleton_<:<.asInstanceOf[A <:< A]
```

ie. use a polymorphic method, returning a singleton value cast to the appropriate type. This is one of occasions where erasure is a win.

Applied to your situation we would have,

```
object SingletonId extends Transform[Any] { def apply(t : Any) = t }
def Id[A] = SingletonId.asInstanceOf[Transform[A]]
```

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> Id("foo")
res0: java.lang.String = foo

scala> Id(23)
res1: Int = 23
```

Comment: so casting a singleton object is the proper way. Now your code uses Identity[Any] instead of Identity[Nothing]. Either seems to work, and as far as the cast is concerned, it seems like this does not matter. Is Any correct, then? In the lib, Nil is of type List[Nothing].

Comment: `Any` is the right choice here. You're expecting to have values of the transformed type (ie. there are things which `SingletonId.apply` will be applied to) you just can't say what their type is. The `Nothing` in `Nil`, on the other hand, is capturing the fact that there is no value at all corresponding to the head of an empty list.

Answer (score 4):

Since the type parameter `T` in `Transform[T]` is invariant, `Transform[Nothing]` is not a subtype of `Transform[String]`, thus the compiler complains about it. But using `Nothing` here doesn't make sense anyway, since there can never be an instance of `Nothing`. So how would you pass one to the `apply` method? You would need to cast yet again. The only option I can see is this:

```
scala> def Id[A] = new Transform[A] { override def apply(t:A) = t }
Id: [A]=> java.lang.Object with Transform[A]

scala> Id(4)
res0: Int = 4

scala> Id("")
res1: java.lang.String = ""
```

Comment: Right, using a factory function instead of a singleton instance would work, and that is how I have it in my code now. But I saw that List uses a singleton typed to Nothing (Nil), so I thought that might be nicer. Passing values is not an issue: I would pass String or Double or whatever I require. You are right about the type variance issue, though, maybe that is the key.

Comment: Passing values IS THE ISSUE. You can pass a String to a method that expects Nothing, because Nothing is a subtype of String and NOT VICE VERSA.

Comment: @Kim Stebel I think you meant: You *can't* pass a String to a method that expects Nothing ...

Comment: @Kim Stebel: you are right. By "passing values is not an issue" I meant that by the time I pass a value into apply(), I am already holding an instance of Identity that was cast to the appropriate type, e.g. Identity[String]. Thanks for your answer and comments.